# Angular callback array push issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a comments section, similar to that of instagram whereby a list of comments is displayed, along side a user profile and usename for each comment.

I have a comments table in parse and a user table in parse, and so I have to perform a further query for each comment to get the profile picture link and username.

I am using angular to do this. I have a comments array to store all the commments, and I am pushing an object onto this array containing:
- Username
- profile picture
- comment

```
var commentQuery = parseQuery.new('Comment');
commentQuery.equalTo("ID", id);
parseQuery.find(commentQuery)
.then(function(results) {
    for(var i =0; i < results.length; i++){
        var comment = results[i].get('comment');
        var userQuery = parseQuery.new('_User');
        userQuery.equalTo("objectId", results[i].get('userObject')[0].id);
        parseQuery.find(userQuery)
        .then(function(user) {  
            var commentObject = {
               comment: comment,
               username : '',
               profile: ''
        }
            commentObject['profile'] = user[0].get('profile_picture')['_url'];
            commentObject['username'] = user[0].get('liveUsername');
            $scope.comments.push(commentObject);    
        })
    }   
})
```

What this then produces in my ng-repeat is a list, with the correct number of comments, however all the comments are the same!

If i print out the comments to the console as they are downlaoded, they are correct. It is at the object creation where things go wrong, and the same data is placed within all comment objects.

[image]

Comment: Change `$scope.commentObject` to `var commentObject`

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.comments` contains multiply `$scope.commentObject`, so when You change `$scope.commentObject` it changes in whole array. You can create new var in `.then(function(user) {` callback and push it to array.

Answer (score 0):

@OP The thing is $scope.commentObject is a reference , so when you update this object all its references are updated to the same value .
Consider this example :

```
var list=[];
$scope.obj="a";
list.push($scope.obj);
console.log(list);  //it will print ['a']
$scope.obj="b";
console.log(list);  //it will print ['b'] , even though  we haven't pushed any new value in the list.
```

You see the problem is that you are pushing the same reference again and again.
To resolve it change your code to the following :

```
parseQuery.find(userQuery)
    .then(function(user) {  
        var commentObject = {
           comment: comment,
           username : '',
           profile: ''
    }
        commentObject['profile'] = user[0].get('profile_picture')['_url'];
        commentObject['username'] = user[0].get('liveUsername');
        $scope.comments.push(commentObject); 
    })
```

Comment: indeed this did fix the issue of duplicated items, however after chnaging as suggested, I now have the same comment repeated under each username. i.e each list item displays the user name and then exactly the same comment. This is something to do with the fact the comment is outside of the inner callback?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions provided are correct, if as stated above, you still have the same comment you should check manually what it's inside the user table